# Sun Solaris 5.10 + jdk 1.6: how to install on a clean machine?

Tags: solaris-10

Can anyone outline the steps for downloading Sun Solaris (assuming I have a free account) and then installing jdk1.6 on it? Something like:

1. Download Sun Solaris iso from http://....
2. Download patches? (for free account?) what should I do... if needed at all.
3. Download jdk package 1.6 for Sun Solaris from http://...
4. Install the jdk using...
5. Now java and javac will work with jdk 1.6

I've tried a few things already but nothing worked.

Comment: If you have Solaris installed it should be as simple as downloading the jdk tar.gz, extracting to some location, and modifying environment variables so the OS knows where to find them.  I have it working fine on a clean install of other nix-based OSes without using a package manager(java packages are less than desirable).  In other nix-based OS, you add the variables JAVA_HOME=whatever/jdkxxx/jre and PATH=$PATH:whatever/jdkxxx/bin to .profile for the users you want to have java or skel/.profile for all new users

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Solaris 10 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/downloads/index.html
2. Patches are not available for free.
3. JDK package is already included in Solaris 10, if you choose the full install option.

(It's Solaris 10, not 5.10 - but once installed, *uname* will report `SunOS 5.10` since *uname* reports the underlying SunOS kernel version, much like *uname* on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 reports the underlying Linux 2.6 kernel version.)

Comment: will it have jdk 1.6? (I don't want 1.5)
thanks

Comment: Yes - `/usr/bin/javac -version` on a machine installed with Solaris 10 9/10 (i.e. the Sept. 2010 release) reports `javac 1.6.0_21`

Comment: You can find the latest JDK downloads here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u25-download-346242.html